# Can users with the same $HOME have separate bash histories?

Tags: command-line, bash, users, bash-history

I have two users, that have the same home directory:

```bash
useradd -m -d /home/mydir user1
useradd -m -d /home/mydir user2
```

and they are in the same group.

But I have a problem, when someone logged in the shell, in mydir appears the `.bash_history` file, of the first user with the commands he made.

Then if the user2 joins and start to make commands, the `.bash_history` remains of the first user with his commands. Is it possible to create bash history for both users?

Comment: "I have two users, that have the same home directory" Please re-evaluate this. What you should do is have 2 homes and share the directories in those home by adding those 2 users to the same group and setting the directories to that group. What you do is going to get messy: there are files in /home/$USER/ that need to be owned by that user and can't be used through the group settings. I have 22 files in /home/$user/ owned by me. Including the infamous `.xsession-errors` and `.ICEauthority`
that have `rw- --- ---`   as setting. Not going to work with 2 users.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, and wanting separate bash histories is a case of wanting *separate program data for each user*, a strong indication that the users need their own individual home directories. If you were to post a new answer about just using separate home directories, I think that would be reasonable and helpful. Whether or nor Romans ends up using that solution, I expect nearly everyone who would describe a situation like the one described here, and who would find this question by searching, to be better served by giving the accounts separate home directories that each can access.

Comment: Either one of the two users cannot use `ssh`, or the two users are security-equivalent because of `.ssh/authorized_keys`. There's probably more takeover methods as well. Typically stuff like this appears only when the home directory is owned by root and writable by neither. I can't imagine what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Possible they have the same UID as well? Not that this makes sense, but it's consistent with everything else.

Comment: @Joshua then those are 1 user. Not 2. And ssh is a good one and there is likely to be more. How about browser cash and history.

Answer (score 8):

I would highly recommend to keep separate user homes for different users and discourage the idea of having a shared home directory for different users.

This makes e.g. custom settings for users impossible, will likely break caches and configs for applications.

---

Concerning your question and assuming you already have made the according changes to `/home/mydir` to make *user2* able to access and write to this directory, you could add the following line in `/home/mydir/.bashrc`:

```bash
HISTFILE="${HISTFILE}_${USER}"
```

Comment: @steeldriver: I did not have any preferences where to place this. '~/.bashrc` would also be an option. Since the `HISTFILE` assignment is within the *bash check* I don't think it is set for other shells. Not sure if there are some kind of best practices where to set such things?

Comment: I recommend putting it in `~/.bashrc`, though for different reasons than @steeldriver suggested. `~/.profile` is only sourced by login shells. If the login shell was not `bash`--as in most graphical logins--subsequent interactive non-login `bash` shells won't have it. Also, even if one starts with a `bash` login shell that sources `~/.profile`, running `bash` from it gives a non-login shell; since `HISTFILE` is not an environment variable (it's just a shell variable; it's not exported), that won't inherit it, and even if it did, the child shell would source `~/.bashrc` which might reassign it.

Comment: @Thomas i'm so sorry i'm not so expert about linux. i have created the two users with `useradd -M -N -d /home/mydir user_name`. So if i remove the -M it should create the directory, where the history, will be created, but with -d the default dir remains the shared dir (when they connect to shell)? Then i have not the .profile in the dir, only the .bash_history of the first user that i try to logged in

Comment: @EliahKagan: yes you are right. Will update my answer. Thanks

Comment: answer is correct so upvoted but it will not fix upcomming issues with `.xsession-errors` and `.ICEauthority`

Comment: when i create an user it creates only the .bash_history file, neither .bashrc and .profile are created @Thomas